# Play Framework 2.4 scala application/form-urlencoded

Tags: scala, playframework

I am new in play framework.
I am using play framework 2.4 with scala.

following is my action

```
def addEvents = Action {    request => 
    val body: AnyContent = request.body
    body.asFormUrlEncoded.map { form =>
        println("Request Body .....  "+ form )
        val n = form.get("email").mkString(" ")
        val eventList = form.get("eventList")
        println("Email .....  "+ n )
        println("Event List .....  "+ eventList )

        Ok("Wop wop wop")
      }.getOrElse {
        BadRequest("Bad bad bad")
     }
   }
```

when i call this action i get following request map :

```
Map(email -> ArrayBuffer(maskedinesh@gmail.com), eventList[0].eventId -> ArrayBuffer(767), eventList[0].eventTital -> ArrayBuffer(test), eventList[0].eventLocation -> ArrayBuffer(shevare Maharashtra India), eventList[0].eventStrat -> ArrayBuffer(2014 Nov 18, 12:14:00), eventList[0].eventEnd -> ArrayBuffer(2014 Nov 18, 13:15:00), eventList[0].customerEmail -> ArrayBuffer(taylor@colburnllc.com), eventList[0].customerPhone -> ArrayBuffer(484 604 0064), eventList[0].customerName -> ArrayBuffer(Taylor Colburn),eventList[0].jobDisc -> ArrayBuffer(), eventList[0].jobNote -> ArrayBuffer(), eventList[0].scheduledEventExpectedDuration -> ArrayBuffer(01:01), eventList[1].eventId -> ArrayBuffer(731), eventList[1].eventTital -> ArrayBuffer(plumbing), eventList[1].eventLocation -> ArrayBuffer(205 Nilgiri Bld. Acharya Society Warje Pune India 411 052), eventList[1].eventStrat -> ArrayBuffer(2014 Nov 18, 13:46:00), eventList[1].eventEnd -> ArrayBuffer(2014 Nov 18, 15:00:00), eventList[1].customerEmail -> ArrayBuffer(maskedinesh@gmail.com), eventList[1].customerPhone -> ArrayBuffer(86 00 396875), eventList[1].customerName -> ArrayBuffer(Aaaa Aaaa), eventList[1].jobDisc -> ArrayBuffer(hehe dhhdjsj), eventList[1].jobNote -> ArrayBuffer(), eventList[1].scheduledEventExpectedDuration -> ArrayBuffer(01:00), eventList[2].eventId -> ArrayBuffer(720), eventList[2].eventTital -> ArrayBuffer(test20), eventList[2].eventLocation -> ArrayBuffer(patiala Punjab IN), eventList[2].eventStrat -> ArrayBuffer(2014 Nov 18, 15:12:00), eventList[2].eventEnd -> ArrayBuffer(2014 Nov 18, 16:12:00), eventList[2].customerEmail -> ArrayBuffer(maskedinesh@gmail.com), eventList[2].customerPhone -> ArrayBuffer(9530581235), eventList[2].customerName -> ArrayBuffer(abhishek Bandhu), eventList[2].jobDisc -> ArrayBuffer(just for test), eventList[2].jobNote -> ArrayBuffer(), eventList[2].scheduledEventExpectedDuration -> ArrayBuffer(01:00), eventList[3].eventId -> ArrayBuffer(721), eventList[3].eventTital -> ArrayBuffer(test 12), eventList[3].eventLocation -> ArrayBuffer(shevare), eventList[3].eventStrat -> ArrayBuffer(2014 Nov 18, 17:14:00), eventList[3].eventEnd -> ArrayBuffer(2014 Nov 18, 18:14:00), eventList[3].customerEmail -> ArrayBuffer(maskedinesh@gmail.com), eventList[3].customerPhone -> ArrayBuffer(9921660151), eventList[3].customerName -> ArrayBuffer(Ajit Parabat), eventList[3].jobDisc -> ArrayBuffer(shrift kg k globalfo), eventList[3].jobNote -> ArrayBuffer(), eventList[3].scheduledEventExpectedDuration -> ArrayBuffer(01:00), key -> ArrayBuffer(3c157cef19f872b0c53bbdb3b99e5899))
```

my question is how to read this data?

```
val n = form.get("email").mkString(" ")
```

the above code give me result as following

```
ArrayBuffer(maskedinesh@gmail.com)
```

and another is

```
val eventList = form.get("eventList")
```

it gives result as 'None'.

How can i read event list?

how i can get email value?

Comment: What does your HTML form look like?

Comment: The request not from html. Its from mobile platform or any other platform.it just REST call.

Comment: Ok.. then what does the body of the request look like?

Comment: HttpClient httpclient;
HttpPost httppost;
ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters;
httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
httppost = new HttpPost(url);
postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
for (int i=0; i< list.size; i++) { 
 postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("eventList["+i+"].eventId","test")); 
 postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("eventList["+i+"].eventTital","test")); 
} 
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters));
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

Comment: This request from android.

Answer (score 0):

```
scala> Map("email" -> collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer("maskedinesh@gmail.com"))
res5: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[String]] = Map(email -> ArrayBuffer(maskedinesh@gmail.com))

scala> res5.get("email").get(0)
res6: String = maskedinesh@gmail.com
```

Comment: what is res:5? What about eventList[0].eventId?